# Error: Uncaught TypeError: data.every() is not a function

Tags: javascript

I tried to delete an array of array within an array if certain values existed

But I am getting this error

```
Error: Uncaught TypeError: data.every() is not a function
```

code below -- which worked for me in an online compiler

```js
const data = [
  ['true', 'visiting-today', 'DVM-Wiessman', 'J-001'],
  ['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens', 'K-001'],
  ['true', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Stevens', 'Z-001'],
  ['false', 'visiting-tommorrow', 'DVM-Kon', 'J-001']
]

const del_values = ['J-001', 'K-001'];

function remove_from_list(list, deleted_values) {
  return list.filter(data => data.every(el => !deleted_values.includes(el)))
}

console.log(remove_from_list(data, del_values))
```

I have also tried replacing includes with `.indexOf()` and `.includes()` but also get a similar error

```
Uncaught TypeError: data.indexOf is not a function

Uncaught TypeError: data.includes is not a function
```

Comment: _“Uncaught `TypeError`: `data.every()` is not a function”_ cannot be an error message. It is either _“Uncaught `TypeError`: `data.every` is not a function”_ or _“Uncaught `TypeError`: `data.every(...)` is not a function”_. The code you posted obviously works fine. Do you know what the error message means? `data` is not an array. If it’s fetched via AJAX, see [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](/q/14220321/4642212).

Comment: small typo but fixed it to data.every, in my own compiler I have written arr, sorry for the confusion, just fixed it @Teemu

Comment: @bombombs What do you mean by _“my own compiler”_?

Comment: @bombombs Most likely `data` is of different type. Can you check its type? `console.log(Array.isArray(data))` before calling the remove function

Comment: @SebastianSimon meant an editor, like VSCode (which is where I am getting the error), but also tested it out in an online compiler (which worked fine)

Comment: @AbhishekKumarTiwari console.log(Array.isArray(data)) would return `true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've provided works, you can test it in your browser's console.

The problem is you're trying to use Array methods on a variable that isn't an Array, so it's not recognizing those functions. if you're returning an answer with Fetch API make sure you add `await/async` or `.then()`.